# Provide access programmatically to BIM 360 services

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360

We are working on providing access to BIM 360 projects programmatically. We allow project admin to select user and role combination to provide access to BIM 360 project.

Once user and role combinations are added, we call import users BIM 360 API and pass the required JSON body. API Reference: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/

There is service access associated with each role. So we are passing the service access information accordingly.

We are able to give access to document_management and project_administration service objects.

But we need to also give access to Project Management, Insight and other available services. If we pass insight or project_management service name we get error as

> Invalid services ["project_management"]

and similar error for insight service.

We are passing below sample JSON body:

```
[
    {
        "email": "userEmail",
        "services": {
            "document_management": {
                "access_level": "admin"
            },
            "project_administration": {
                "access_level": "admin"
            },
            "project_management": {
                "access_level": "admin"
            }
        },
        "company_id": "companyId",
        "industry_roles": [
            "roleid1",
            "roleid2"
        ]
    }
]
```

If we remove project_management object from above JSON, the access works fine.

How can we provide access to these and other available services? or are we missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a known limitation of Admin API :-(  although it is a high demanded feature.

We have a wish logged against it:

```
ACSADMIN-530 (was HQ-3034): “API wish: adding users beyond Docs”
```

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Thank you Mikako for the update! I read article https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-hq-patch-project-user-api-will-remove-access-other-next-generation-new-bim360-modules which mentions it supports only two service's access. But that was older article so just wanted to check if there is any update.